# How to load a Dll (c++) into at C# Application at runime

Tags: c#, function, dll, runtime

I have this code in a c++ file, with compiles to a dll.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "WHUU.h"

#include "stdafx.h"

typedef int (__stdcall * Callback)(const int text);

static int x , y= 0;

Callback Handler = 0;

int getX()
{
    return x;
}

void setX(int i)
{
    x = i;
}

void setY(int i)
{
    y = i;
}
int getY()
{
    return y;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall SetCallback(Callback handler) {
  Handler = handler;
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall addX(int x) {
    setX(x);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall addY(int y) {
    setY(y);


}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall TestCallback() {
    int z = getX() + getY();
  int retval = Handler(z);
}
```

My c# application now has to load this dll on runtime. Add to the callback and call the functions. I dont want to use a class. I could load the class and with

```
 Type[] types = moduleAssembly.GetTypes();
```

But this overkill! Also  c++ is not managed.

I mean its so tiny! (and yes this is an example , but the "real" is just as big as this example).

How do i do that?

Thanks you for your help!

add:

- i dont like frameworks (like pinvoke / assembly)
- the function names / types are fixed and will never change (think of a driver.dll read write)
- this dll is written by customers so it should be as easy as possible!

Comment: The requirements are fairly nonsensical.  Nobody ever asks for the hardest way to do it.  And you really *do* want to take advantage of pinvoke.  Asking the client to write a COM version of this code so you don't have to do the hard work is probably going to go poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used P/Invoke, post my own cause the callback was not included by the others. But they were good answers! The C# Applicationhas use this [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD8Tm.png).

The Code for the Application is this : (mind it is a prototype to answer a technical question)

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

        private delegate int Callback(int text);
        private Callback mInstance;   // Ensure it doesn't get garbage collected

        [DllImport(@"C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\kalkulatorius\Debug\WHUU1.dll")]
        private static extern void SetCallback(Callback fn);
        [DllImport(@"C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\kalkulatorius\Debug\WHUU1.dll")]
        private static extern void addX(int x);
        [DllImport(@"C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\kalkulatorius\Debug\WHUU1.dll")]
        private static extern void addY(int y);
        [DllImport(@"C:\\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\kalkulatorius\Debug\WHUU1.dll")]

        private static extern void TestCallback(); 

        private int Handler(int text) 
        {
          textBox3.Text = text.ToString();
          return 42;                       
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
          mInstance = new Callback(Handler); // to set the callback in lib 
          SetCallback(mInstance);            // could also be withhin constructor!

          addX(int.Parse(textBox1.Text)); // other people in this thread posted this correct answer
          addY(int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
          TestCallback();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }
```

So if you want to use a c++ lib with functions and callbacks (like in the question posted) you can use this.

But how to change the lib?

- The Path to the lib is hardcoded (see [dllImport ......] ). But you
  can swop the lib in filesystem. This can happen AFTER you build this
  application.
- If the lib is not on the given path an exception is thrown. So if
  your program wants to use this lib first check the lib is present on the filesystem. 
  (not included  in this simple prototype)
- So to switch functionality (swop a driver lib ect) you copy a different lib with the
  same name into the given path. (Copy paste - maybe change name)

This solution has the least overhead and is good if you never change the interface of an dll after the application was build!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it over p/invoke, as example:

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private extern static int yourFunction(int var1, int var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

> i dont like frameworks (like pinvoke / assembly)

I'll suggest P/Invoke anyway. I don't think there are any reasonable alternatives. Perhaps writing a managed wrapper in managed C++, but really?

When you use P/Invoke the .NET runtime will dynamically load the DLL's that you have specified (and this is done when you first call the function). There is no reason to use P/Invoke to call `LoadLibrary` first.

Comment: this question was posted because of a heated discussion that you can call .net lib functions without any framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use P/Invoke to call the dll directly, or you can create a C++/CLI wrapper for it.

Here's how you can do it using P/Invoke:
Add the compiled dll to your C# project, set its 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy Always'. and call it like this:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("cppdll.dll")]
    private static extern void addX(int x);

    [DllImport("cppdll.dll")]
    private static extern void addY(int y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        addX(5);
        addY(7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be through API. Find below an example for the setX and getX method from your sample above.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string libraryPath, IntPtr fileHandle, int actionFlag);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr libraryHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr dllPointer, string functionName);

    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    private delegate void setX (int i);
    private delegate int getX();

    private setX setXDel;
    private getX getXDel;

    public Constructor()
    {
        loadLib();
    }

    public void YourMethod()
    {
        setXDel(100);
        int y = getXDel();
        Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());
    }

    private void loadLib()
    {
        string path = "your dll path";
        ptr = LoadLibraryEx(path, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception("Cannot load dll.");

        IntPtr addressPtr = GetProcAddress(ptr, "setX");
        setXDel = (setX)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressPtr, typeof(setX));

        addressPtr = GetProcAddress(unrarPtr, "getX");
        getXDel = (getX)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressPtr, typeof(getX));

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            FreeLibrary(ptr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your are using P/Invoke to provide your own implementation of something similar to P/Invoke. Just use P/Invoke instead.